# Phonegap app unable to connect to development server due to untrusted certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, certificate

I am trying to allow an HTML5 app deployed to an iPad via Phonegap to connect to web services provided by my development server. The development server has a self-signed certificate. I was able to export my cert in p12 format (with the private key), and using the iPhone Configuration Utility I was able to create a configuration profile and and install it to my iPad. When I look under General -> Profiles on the iPad I can see my configuration profile, and it says "Verified" with a green checkmark. However, it is signed with a signing certificate generated by the iPhone Configuration Utility that is NOT trusted. I believe this is causing web services to fail.

If I hit web services on a production server everything works fine, because the certificate that server has is verified by a major 3rd party issuer. The only problem is hitting my development server. I am able to hit the development server using the host name that the self-signed certificate was issued for by having my iPad hit a proxy server, which has an /etc/hosts entry that resolves to the correct host name. I can hit this site in Chrome on the iPad so I know that is working. However, Chrome also throws up a warning because the certificate is not trusted. It SHOULD be trusted. This works fine on a laptop computer, or in the iOS simulator (for that I had to import the cert into the simulator). It is only on an actual physical device that it won't work.

Surely this kind of dev setup is typical for iOS apps using web services. Can anyone suggest a course of action? Is there a way to get the signing certificate produced by the iPhone Configuration Utility to be trusted?